# Sqlite optimization for MAX query on non-leftmost column on index

Tags: database, sqlite, optimization, indexing

I noticed the online page about [SQLite's query optimizer](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html) guarantees that queries of the form `SELECT MAX(colA) FROM TABLE` can be optimized if there is an index whose leftmost column is `colA`.

However, I'm less clear about what happens when an index is used to narrow the table based on an equality in `WHERE` clause, such that the next column in the index is the one that I'm taking a `MAX` on. Based on the structure of the index, the maximum value should be quickly accessible as the last row in the subset of the index satisfying the `WHERE` clause. For example, given an index on `colA` and `colB`, it should be possible to find `SELECT MAX(colB) FROM SillyTable WHERE colA = 1` without scanning all 6 rows associated with `colA = 1`:

```
Index of SillyTable on colA, colB:
colA    colB    rowid
1       1       4
1       2       5
1       4       2
1       5       8
1       6       3     # This is the one
2       1       1
2       5       6
2       8       7
```

Does SQLite actually optimize a query like this, or will it scan all the rows that satisfy the `WHERE` clause? If it does a scan, how can I change the query to make it run faster?

My specific use case is similar to the `SillyTable` example. I created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Product(
  ProductTypeID      INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ProductID          INTEGER NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(ProductTypeID, ProductID),
  FOREIGN KEY(ProductTypeID)
    REFERENCES ProductType(ProductTypeID)
);
```

`ProductTypeID` is not particularly selective for the table; I might have many rows with the same `ProductTypeID` but different `ProductID`. `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` tells me that my query uses an index automatically built for the composite primary key, but that is true whether it scans or binary-searches the subset of rows found with the index:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT MAX(ProductID) FROM Product
  WHERE ProductTypeID = ?;

=>

SEARCH TABLE Product USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_Product_1(ProductTypeID=?)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is shown in the EXPLAIN output:

```
sqlite> EXPLAIN SELECT MAX(ProductID) FROM Product WHERE ProductTypeID = ?;
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     17    0                    00  Start at 17  
1     Null           0     1     2                    00  r[1..2]=NULL 
2     OpenRead       1     3     0     k(2,,)         02  root=3 iDb=0; sqlite_autoindex_Product_1
3     Variable       1     3     0                    00  r[3]=parameter(1,)
4     IsNull         3     13    0                    00  if r[3]==NULL goto 13
5     Affinity       3     1     0     D              00  affinity(r[3])
6     SeekLE         1     13    3     1              00  key=r[3]     
7       IdxLT          1     13    3     1              00  key=r[3]     
8       Column         1     1     4                    00  r[4]=Product.ProductID
9       CollSeq        0     0     0     (BINARY)       00               
10      AggStep0       0     4     1     max(1)         01  accum=r[1] step(r[4])
11      Goto           0     13    0                    00  max() by index
12    Prev           1     7     0                    00               
13    AggFinal       1     1     0     max(1)         00  accum=r[1] N=1
14    Copy           1     5     0                    00  r[5]=r[1]    
15    ResultRow      5     1     0                    00  output=r[5]  
16    Halt           0     0     0                    00               
17    Transaction    0     0     1     0              01  usesStmtJournal=0
18    Goto           0     1     0                    00
```

To make the code generator simpler, SQLite always creates a loop for the aggregation (lines 6 to 12). However, for `max()`, this loop aborts after the first successful step (line 11).